# Firebase Local Unit Testing Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "dev~not-a-project"

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to unit test my Firebase Cloud Functions in the Local Emulator Suite.
For that I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#stubbed-data) unit testing guide on firebase.com.
However it doesn't explain how to unit test in the Local Emulator Suite so I have to improvise a bit.
I set up my test the following way:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = '127.0.0.1:9099'
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"

const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();
const firebase = require('@firebase/testing')


const MY_PROJECT_ID = "ProjectID"
```

Since I use the wrapper of firebase, I'm able to invoke my OnCreate function directly. The function changes the content of a created document and eventually updates the saved document with new data. However, since the wrapper doesn't create the document, I have to create it first in the test and make sure that it doesn't run the OnCreate Function.

**The Problem**

When trying to update the document in the OnCreate Function, I always get the following error:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "dev~not-a-project"
```

I checked that the path is right multiple times. I fear that the local Emulator Suite just doesn't work with that kind of testing yet.

Does anybody have a solution?